# execute setInterval on condition jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my Master Page load `checkNotification();` function gets called after each 1 minute.on master page there is one drop down `cmbTicketStatus`.if the drop down value is 4 then DO NOT RUN setInterval function.

tried some code:-

```
function masterPageLoad() {
    setInterval(function() { 
         if($('#cmbTicketStatus').val != '4')
         {
         checkNotification();
         } }, 60000);
         }
```

My Project is like for e.g. when i select "ONE" in drop down click on SHOW i see 50 rows in my page and its efficient to call setInterval function on those 50 rows becoz the function takes somw row data in it.
BUT
if i select "FOUR" in drop down click on SHOW i gets 15000 rows in my page. HERE I DONT WANT setInterval function to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var id;
$('#cmbTicketStatus').change(function(){
 if(this.val()!=4)
 {
  if(!id){
   id = setInterval(function(){/*your function*/},6000);
  }
 }
 else
 {
  clearInterval(id);
  id=null;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$('#cmbTicketStatus').val()`. `val` is a function and not a property.